# Can background page use window.location

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create chrome extension that will scrap data from my webpage and then will display it in browser action window. I wanted to use background page for this, cause if i understand extensions correctly, it is only element capable of non-stop working, without need of visible tab.

The problem is, the script i wrote for background.js doesn't work properly, when i use background.js:

```
var location = window.location.href = 'http://localhost/index.php';
console.log(location);
```

manifest.json:

```
"background": {
 "scripts": ["src/background/background.js"]
},
```

The answer i get is chrome-extension://some_random_text/_generated_background_page.html.

It is possible to use background pages to navigate to my webpage, then fill some forms and scrap data for later use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but I recently wanted to do exactly the same.
So I'll provide an answer for others who are interested.

Setting window.location still does not work in Chrome52.
There is a workaround though. You can first fetch the web page with fetch(), and then use document.write to set the content.

This works fine, and you can then query the document and do everything you want with it.

Here is an example. (Note that I'm using the fetch API, arrow functions and LET, which all work fine now in Chrome52).

```
fetch("http://cnn.com").then((resp) => {
  return resp.text();
}).then((html) => {
  document.open("text/html");
  document.write(html);
  document.close();

  // IMPORTANT: need to use setTimeout because chrome takes a little 
  // while to update the document.
  setTimeout(function() {
    let allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    // Do something with the links.
  }, 250);
});
```

Comment: I covered it in some more detail on my Blog here: https://theduke.at/blog/develop/how-to-crawl-web-pages-in-google-chrome-extension

Answer (score -2):

A chrome extension has two main parts, the extension process and the browser itself. The Background Page works on the extension process. It does not have direct access and information about your webpages.

To have scripts working non-stop on your webpages, you will need to use [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

You can then communicate between your Content Script and your Background Page using [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

**contentScript.js**

```
var location = window.location.href = 'http://localhost/index.php';
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({location: location}, function(response) {});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request.location);
    });
```